# Tumblr "Sourceurl" only showing on certain posts

Tags: html, themes, tumblr

For some reason, on my blog, the source url is only showing up on some posts, and I can't figure out why.

This post here: http://kylesethgray.com/post/49192734862/smartphone-feud

and this one: http://kylesethgray.com/post/48863233123/twitter-for-mac-updated

both have the 'content source' url filled out in the post Data, but only the 'twitter for mac' post shows it on the site.

[image: Twitter post]
[image: smart phone ad]

This has happened on some other posts too, and I don't know why it is. They're both 'link' posts, so anything and everything in the theme code is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I fixed it. I guess tumblr has a bug where it won't recognize URLS without 'www'